# What is the best loop to use?

Tags: c#, foreach, ms-word

I'm making a Microsoft Word addin that integrates with our EDRMS software.

On this addin, there is a button that will create a new Word Document and save it into the EDRMS.

However, this button is also available when an existing Document is opened too.

I want to be able to add some sort of validation so that if the User clicks on the "Create New" button on an existing Document, a message box appears saying that the Document already exists.

I have been using the foreach loop, which does not work well as it stops at the first result.

What is the best loop that I can use that will go through all the results first then determine if the document exists or if a new document can be created.

My code is below:

```
    private void btnNewDoc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string docName = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Name;

            string res = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(docName);

            string fileloc = Path.GetFullPath(docName);

            //searches through all existing documents that are checked out to me
            TrimMainObjectSearch recser = new TrimMainObjectSearch(db, BaseObjectTypes.Record);
            recser.SetSearchString("checkedOutBy:me");

            foreach (Record resultRecord in recser)
            {
                //if the document doesnt appear in the checked out results, then create the new document
                if (res != resultRecord.Title)
                {
                    //code to create the new doc
                }
                //otherwise display a message
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("This is an existing document - " + resultRecord.Number.ToString());
                }
            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: *I have been using the foreach loop, which does not work well as it stops at the first result.* A loop only stops if you explicitly tell to do so, or there are no more items to iterate over.

Comment: The `foreach` loop will behave the same as any other loop in this respect.  Is the problem being caught by the `res != resultRecord.Title` test, or is an exception being thrown?  An exception not caught inside the loop will break out of any loop.

Comment: can you explain what the value of `res` is and what `resultRecord.Title` is when you make your first iteration..? this will determine if you need a break; statement inside the foreach or not.. if worse comes to worse..then convert it to a for loop and determine what the loop count should be based on the `recser` size

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin It goes through each result individually, so for example, if the first result in the search is NOT equal to the Active Document, then it will think that the document doesn't exist and hence will attempt to create the Document.

Comment: @MethodMan res is the name of the active document and resultRecord.Title is the name of the document in the EDRMS search results. If the value for both are not equal, thats when I want the new document to be created

Comment: @razor_ray I know that .. I am asking what is the actual value of both when you use the debugger... ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop

```
foreach (Record resultRecord in recser)
{
    //if the document doesnt appear in the checked out results, then create the new document
    if (res != resultRecord.Title)
    {
        //code to create the new doc
    }
    //otherwise display a message
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This is an existing document - " + resultRecord.Number.ToString());
    }
}
```

if the first result isn't the same as `res`, you create a new document.  That's not the behavior you want.  It is unclear whether you break out of the loop at that point, as you have not shown code details.

```
bool foundExistingTitle = false;
foreach (Record resultRecord in recser)
{

    //if the document doesnt appear in the checked out results, then create the new document
    if (res == resultRecord.Title)
    {
        foundExistingTitle = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (foundExistingTitle)
{
    MessageBox.Show("This is an existing document - " + resultRecord.Number.ToString());
}
```

}

You can greatly simplify that code if you want to use Linq.

```
bool foundExistingTitle = resultRecord.Where(r => r.Title == res).Any();
```

Comment: that is exactly what I needed Eric. Thanks for your help!